# Count rows of groups after sorting data in Power BI

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, group

I have a table with the following columns:

- different products: A, B, C...
- date and time of purchase.

I have sorted the table to arrange the data in descending order of date, latest to earliest. I want to count the number of same products that are purchased together. For example: after sorting the table, my products column will look like A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,C,C,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,C...
What I want is to group them n count the number of same products that are together:

- A - 2
- B - 4
- C - 6
- B - 3
- A - 4
- C - 1...

Does anyone know how to do this in Power BI? Even if there are multiple purchases of the same products **back to back** on different dates, I still want them all (same products) grouped together to count them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you ordered your data, add an index column in power query editor as shown below-

[image]

now create a **Measure** as below-

```
consecutive_count = 

var current_row_product = MAX('your_table_name'[product])
var current_row_index = MAX('your_table_name'[Index])
var next_row_index = max('your_table_name'[Index]) + 1

var next_row_product = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('your_table_name'[product]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[Index] = next_row_index
    )
)

var min_consecutive_product_index = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('your_table_name'[Index]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[Index] <= current_row_index
        && 'your_table_name'[product] <> current_row_product
    )
) + 0

return 
if(
    next_row_product <> current_row_product, 
    current_row_index - min_consecutive_product_index
)
```

Now add Index, product and new measure to a table visuala and final output will be as below-

[image]

**First** column Index may looks annoying but you can not remove. But you can handle that using 0 width for the first column so that end users do not see the column.

---

### **UPDATE**

Found a very special way to do it in **Power Query Editor**. Just follow this below steps-

1. Duplicate your base table and create a new table so that base value remains unchanged.
2. Keep only Product column ensuring the order not changed. this will looks like below-

[image]

3. Now apply group by with an additional parameter as marked in red in the below image. you can see your expected output with these very simple steps.

[image]

Now you have a physical table and you can use this new value anywhere you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly. However, I need to use these values for another calculation. Is there a way to retrieve certain values from the list or create this as a calculated column/table instead?

Comment: @DVR15 please check my updated answer and also put an up vote if it really helped.